# Insert into Database Table only if DISTINCT

Tags: c#, sql, select, insert, distinct

I have a list containing values that need to be added to a table and for which I have coded all the necessary requirements however I need the values to be added **ONLY if they do not exist** in the table already.

My Insert Statement:

```
public static void InjectNewWords(List<string> newWords)
    {
        string conString = "Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=QABase;Integrated Security=True";

        List<string> distinctWords = newWords.Distinct().ToList();

        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(conString))
        {
            connection.Open();
            string sqlIns = "insert into NewWords(WordList) values (@WordList)";
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sqlIns, connection);


            command.Parameters.Add("@WordList", SqlDbType.Text);
            try
            {
                foreach (string word in distinctWords)
                {
                    command.Parameters["@WordList"].Value = word;
                    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
            }
            catch(Exception ee)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(ee.ToString());
                }


            try
            {

                Int32 rowsAffected = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                //Console.WriteLine("RowsAffected: {0}", rowsAffected);
                //("Rows Affected: " + rowsAffected);
                connection.Close();
                newWords.Clear();
                distinctWords.Clear();
            }
```

What changes should I make in order to get this done, guys? :) Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

perhaps just add a `where` to the `insert`? (and a unique index for good measure and efficiency of evaluation):

```
 where not exists (select 1 from NewWords where WordList = @WordList)
```

Answer (score 0):

if you have stored list of names in another table then you may use this query

```
insert into tbl_name 
select * from tbl_name 
where col_name not in(
    select * from ano_tbl_name
);
```